# Fubini-Study measure on a product

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, algebraic-geometry

I read that if $\Omega_2$ is the Fubini-Study form on $\mathbb{P}_1\times\mathbb{P}_1$, and $\Omega$ the Fubini-Study form on $\mathbb{P}_1$, then for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{P}_1\times\mathbb{P}_1$, one has $\Omega_2(x,y)=\Omega(x)+\Omega(y)$.

I wish to justify this equality. What is the exact definition of the Fubini-Study form on the product space?

Comment: I wonder if the intent is for you to embed the product in $\mathbb P^3$ via Segre and restrict the FS form from there. I would have to sit down and work this out.

Comment: Can you help me writing it down?

Comment: I thought about something like that:
the image under Segre of the product of projective spaces is $\{(x_iy_j)\}$ The square of the norm of such a guy is $|x_0y_0|^2+|x_0y_1|^2+|x_1y_0|^2+|x_1y_1|^2=(|x_0|^2+|x_1|^2)(|y_0|^2+|y_1|^2)$. I think that with the definition $\partial\overline{\partial}\log|Z|$ of the Fubini-Study form, we can do something.

Answer (score -1):

In the language of Quantum Mechanics, if we can say that the ket $ |\psi> $ is separable then it can clearly be written as $ \psi> = |\psi_{S_{1}}>\otimes |\psi_{S_{2}}>$ for subspaces $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ then the full metric is the sum of the metrics on the subspaces $g = g_{S_{1}}+g_{S_{2}}$.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know Quantum Mechanics. Is there any translation of it in an other language?

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Expand.

Comment: Autolatry: expand yourself! Write down **explicitly** the Fubiny-Study *form* for  $\mathbb P^2$ and show its relationship to that of $\mathbb P^1$. You haven't even mentioned Fubini-Study *forms* in your answer, only metrics...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg You're the one with the issue to my comment, you explain why it's not relevant. All the best.